# Running poetry fails with /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, python-poetry

I just installed poetry with the following install script

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3
```

However, when I execute poetry it fails with the following error

```
$ poetry
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 20.04, is this an issue with the upgrade or with poetry?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

poetry is dependent on whatever `python` is and doesn't attempt to use a specific version of python unless otherwise specified.

The above issue will exist on ubuntu systems moving forward 20.04 onwards as python2.7 is deprecated and the `python` command does not map to python3.x

You'll find specifying an alias for python to python3 won't work ( unless, perhaps you specify this in your bashrc instead of any other shell run command file ) as poetry spins it's own shell to execute commands.

Install the following package instead

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

It should be noted that you can install python2.7 if you want to and poetry should run fine.

Comment: With one of the next releases, the poetry installer will add the available python interpreter to the shebang. See this [merged PR](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/1878). For me, a system that hasn't a `python` executable, is broken. But sadly [PEP394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) allows this, so we have to take care about  it.

Comment: I agree with that sentiment, and was surprised to see 20.04 ship without a `python`. Looking over that pep, it's surprising to see a lack of `python` permissible even when python 2 or 3 is supported

Comment: How to solve this issue on MacOS?

Comment: @Adelin run `which python3` to get python3 executable path and create a symlink with this path to a bin directory named python.    
You can always `echo $PATH` to check what directory you can create the symlink in.    
    
The command looks like this on my computer `ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11 ~/bin/python
`

Answer (score 10):

**FOR MAC USERS**

Run this:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
```

You should get something like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 irfan  admin  34 Nov 11 16:32 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 irfan  admin  41 Nov 11 16:32 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 irfan  admin  36 Nov 11 16:32 /usr/local/bin/python3.7 -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 irfan  admin  43 Nov 11 16:32 /usr/local/bin/python3.7-config -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 irfan  admin  37 Nov 11 16:32 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3.7m
lrwxr-xr-x  1 irfan  admin  44 Nov 11 16:32 /usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config -> ../Cellar/python/3.7.5/bin/python3.7m-config
```

Change the default python symlink to the version you want to use from above.
Note that, we only need to choose the one that ends with python3.*. Please avoid using the ones' that end with config or python3.*m or python3.*m-config.

Run this:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Check if it's working:

```
python --version # Should output Python 3.7.5
```

Answer (score 5):

Also an issue on some other Ubuntu versions/variants (Mint 19.3 here).

The `python-is-python3` answer from `arshbot` is a good option, alternatively I found just tweaking the script that invokes poetry fixed it for me: A more delicate approach, but also more fragile in case the script gets updated (so overwritten) in future. So anyway here's that lightweight/fragile option:

Edit the script,

```
vi ~/.poetry/bin/poetry
```

(other editors are available etc) and change the top line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

becomes

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

sorted!

This is only likely to be needed as a temporary workaround considering `finswimmer`'s comment, from which it seems poetry will be more intelligent about using python3 in future in this situation.

Comment: Still using this, so I guess is not as temporary as it may seem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by a broken venv, which is trying to use a generic call to "python" instead of the versionated "python3" command.

For me, the solution was to only:

Remove the current venv:

```
rm -r venv/
```

Then, recreate the venv using python3:

```
python3 -m venv ./venv
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get for `poetry install` - `No such file or directory: 'python'`
Try to update your python command with update-alternatives:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python

There are 5 programs which provide 'python'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/libexec/no-python
   2           /usr/bin/python2
   3           /usr/bin/python3
   4           /usr/bin/python3.9
   5           /usr/bin/python3.11
```

The default was "no-python", so after I changed it to "python3.11" `poetry install` worked!